# How to find the average?

Tags: python

I have a dict() like so

```
{'5/2020': 51, '11/2021': 16, '10/2021': 13, '1/2020': 15,
 '2/2021': 5, '3/2020': 16, '10/2020': 13, '6/2021': 20, 
 '9/2021': 25, '2/2020': 12, '1/2021': 23, '11/2020': 31, 
 '4/2020': 20, '7/2021': 14, '12/2020': 23}
```

How do I find the average value per year?

Comment: can you explain more about your data first and also provide what you tried

Comment: are you aware that your dictionary contains duplicate keys? and that duplicates will be removed?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to accomplish this, one is such as,

```py
data = {'5/2020': 51, '11/2021': 16, '11/2021': 13, '1/2020': 15,
 '2/2021': 5, '1/2020': 16, '10/2020': 13, '6/2021': 20, 
 '6/2021': 25, '2/2020': 12, '1/2021': 23, '11/2020': 31, 
 '2/2020': 20, '7/2021': 14, '10/2020': 23}

average_value = sum(data.values())/len(data) # within all date range.
print(average_value)
```

### Edited:

***Sorry** as I overlooked the main idea.*

After thinking for a while I figured out that you can utilize all data (which is not possible here due to the presence of same `key`) if the dates are given in full form, say *dd/mm/yyyy* or others.

Thus depending on the dates (that can be extended even further with properly specified format) you can calculate the average for different years; different months of the same year etc. And this is what I came up with :

```py
import datetime
import statistics


def calculate_average(raw_data: dict, date_format: str = "%d/%m/%Y", date_precision: int = 1) -> dict:
    """
    Returns a dictionary of date-data and date-based average as a key-value pair for a given 'raw_data' as dict. It takes the following kwargs :
        'date_format' : Format of the date in which date will be parsed, defaults to '%m/%Y' (i.e. mm/yyyy). This must comply with the date style used in 'raw_data'.
        'date_precision' : A positive integer to determine the no. of values taking into account for the average-calculation. This value (1 means only year, 2 means only year and month, 3 means only year, month and day etc.) will be considered for date precision. Defaults to 1.
    """
    # Some type or value checking can be done here.
    D = date_wise_data = { }
    for date_string, val in raw_data.items():
        y, m, d, hr, mt, sec, *_ = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format).timetuple() # To unpack all year, month, day etc. Other data can be added also.
        data_type = (y, m, d, hr, mt, sec)[:date_precision] # Type of date-data, based on which average will be calculated.
        D[data_type] = D.get(data_type, [ ])+[val]
    averages = map(statistics.fmean, D.values())
    return dict(zip(D, averages))


d = {
    '5/2020': 51,
    '11/2021': 16, #
    '11/2021': 13,
    '1/2020': 15, #
    '2/2021': 5,
    '1/2020': 16,
    '10/2020': 13, #
    '6/2021': 20, #
    '6/2021': 25,
    '2/2020': 12, #
    '1/2021': 23,
    '11/2020': 31,
    '2/2020': 20,
    '7/2021': 14,
    '10/2020': 23,
}


print(calculate_average(d, "%m/%Y"))
# [28.2, 16.0]
```

If the `keys` are modified (with same `values`), the average in every month in the same year can be calculated as well.

```
d = {
    '1/5/2020': 51,
    '2/11/2021': 16,
    '5/11/2021': 13,
    '7/1/2020': 15,
    '18/2/2021': 5,
    '22/1/2020': 16,
    '18/10/2020': 13,
    '23/6/2021': 20,
    '20/6/2021': 25,
    '27/2/2020': 12,
    '17/1/2021': 23,
    '28/11/2020': 31,
    '14/2/2020': 20,
    '30/7/2021': 14,
    '31/10/2020': 23,
}

print(calculate_average(d, date_precision = 2))
#{(2020, 5): 51.0, (2021, 11): 14.5, (2020, 1): 15.5, (2021, 2): 5.0, (2020, 10): 18.0, (2021, 6): 22.5, (2020, 2): 16.0, (2021, 1): 23.0, (2020, 11): 31.0, (2021, 7): 14.0}
```

Hope this will be helpful as I generalized it upto some level, which can be extended possibly even further.

Comment: it asks for average value _per year_

Answer (score 0):

You can think of this problem as a two step process. First you need to group the data by year, then secondly you need to take the average of each year.

```
import statistics

data = {'5/2020': 51, '11/2021': 16, '10/2021': 13, '1/2020': 15,
        '2/2021': 5,  '3/2020': 16,  '10/2020': 13, '6/2021': 20, 
        '9/2021': 25, '2/2020': 12,  '1/2021': 23,  '11/2020': 31, 
        '4/2020': 20, '7/2021': 14,  '12/2020': 23}

def group_by_year(data):
    sorted = {}
    for date, val in data.items():
        year = date.split('/')[-1]
        sorted.setdefault(year, []).append(val)
    return sorted

for year, vals in group_by_year(data).items():
    print(year + ' average:', statistics.mean(vals))
```

which outputs

```
2020 average: 22.625
2021 average: 16.571428571428573
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'5/2020': 51, '11/2021': 16, '11/2021': 13, '1/2020': 15,
 '2/2021': 5, '1/2020': 16, '10/2020': 13, '6/2021': 20, 
 '6/2021': 25, '2/2020': 12, '1/2021': 23, '11/2020': 31, 
 '2/2020': 20, '7/2021': 14, '10/2020': 23}

avg_dict = {}
# Group all the values by year
for k, v in data.items():
    avg_dict.setdefault(k.split('/')[-1], []).append(v)

# Compute the average
for k, v in avg_dict.items():
    avg_dict[k] = sum(v)/len(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` (first you need to sort the data (it's crucial)) to group the items by the year and then you can just iterate over the values of those groups and calculate the average using `statistics.mean`. Also your dictionary contains duplicate keys, which means that only the last key (and value) will be kept. Also your date format is not that great, you should follow the ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```py
import itertools
import statistics

data = {'5/2020': 51, '11/2021': 13, '2/2021': 5,
        '1/2020': 16, '6/2021': 25, '1/2021': 23,
        '11/2020': 31, '2/2020': 20, '7/2021': 14,
        '10/2020': 23}


def key(x):
    return x[0].split('/')[-1]


averages = {}
sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key=key)
for year, items in itertools.groupby(sorted_data, key=key):
    averages[year] = statistics.mean(val for _, val in items)

print(averages)

# Output:
# {'2020': 28.2, '2021': 16}
```